# How to control what is shown in Windows 10 "recently added" programs list?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, startmenu

The Windows 10 start menu will show recently added programs after you run an installer.

In my case, the installer installs more than one program to Start Menu. For some reason it is picking one of them and showing it as "recently added", but I'd like to specify that a different one shows up there.

**How can this been set / controlled?**

I have tried to change the order which the installer adds entries to the start menu, but that didn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Windows internally tracks this, but at least if you are using **Inno Setup** it is possible to disable tracking the installed program as recently added by using a flag:

> ```
> excludefromshowinnewinstall
> ```
>
> Prevents the Start menu entry for the new shortcut from receiving a
> highlight on Windows 7 and additionally prevents the new shortcut from
> being automatically pinned the Start screen on Windows 8 (or later).
>
> Ignored on earlier Windows versions.

Ref.: https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection

So it should be possible to apply this exclusionary flag to all but the program which is intended to be shown in the list.